# Styling HAML using SASS

Tags: haml, sass, styling

hi this should be a quick one i am very new to both sass and haml i know they are very delicate languages. i am looping through an Array of Structs, i would like to color the information turned out by the loop and not anything else. my haml looks like this:

```
%table
  - test = sprint.work_by_developer
  %tr
    - test.each do |data|
      %td.column.developer_name
        = data.name
        \:
      %td.type_of_work
        Features: 
        = data.features
        %br/
        Chores: 
        = data.chores
        %br/
        bugs:
        = data.bugs
```

my sass looks like this:

```
.developer_name
  :width 70px
  :padding 13px
  :font-weight bold


.type_of_work
  :width 155px 
  :color #2B65EC
```

i would really like the numbers from data.features, data.chores and data.bugs to be a light blue color: any ideas, tips, tricks, comments, concerns and critisms are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap them in a span with a specific class and add the appropriate rules for that class.

```
%span.light-blue= data.features

.light-blue
  :color ...
```